# Unintended recursive loop with __repr__ method

Tags: python, recursion, repr

I want to display a list of all accessible attribute of an instance, so i try this

```py
class Test:
    a=2     #initializing some attribute
    b=1     #initializing some attribute
    def some_method(self):
        attr=[]                 
        for k in [i for i in dir(self) if not i.startswith('__')]:
            attr.append(f'{k}={getattr(self,k)}')      #to collect all attributes and their values pair
        return attr
    def __repr__(self):                                #because i want to overload print behavior
        return str(self.some_method())
some_instance=Test()
print(some_instance)
```

And it returned an error:

```py
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Why did that happen ? And how to fix that ?

Comment: Well if there is a cycle in your object (for example the list contains a reference to `self`, or one of the elements somehow aims to print `self`), then you get in a recursive loop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `a`,`b`,`some_method` are everything i have in the instance, which of them cause this problem ?

Comment: @TuanDoan: usually `dir` has more than only these attributes. For example `some_method`, etc. The `repr(..)` of `Test().some_method` is `<bond method Test.some_method of repr(self))`, hence the recursion, so the `repr(..)` of `Test().some_method` results in a new call to `repr(self)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `repr(Test().some_method)` calls `repr` of the object where it lives, yielding in a never ending son-father `repr` method call stack.
If you are not really interested in showing callable members you can filter them out so that they never get asked to be part of a string:

```py
class Test:
    a=2     #initializing some attribute
    b=1     #initializing some attribute
    def some_method(self):
        attr=[]                 
        for k in dir(self):
            val = getattr(self, k)
            if not k.startswith('__') and not callable(val):
                attr.append(f'{k}={val}')      #to collect all attributes and their values pair
        return attr
    def __repr__(self):                                #because i want to overload print behavior
        return str(self.some_method())
some_instance=Test()
```

Then `print(some_instance)` shows

```
['a=2', 'b=1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__str__` instead of `__repr__` to overload printing.
In case you must use `__repr__` then use the `isinstance()` to compare the type of attribute values against `types.MethodType` in the standard library.