# When did CPython's `repr` start handling recursive data structures?

Tags: python, cpython, recursive-datastructures, repr

This MWE in the past would cause a stack overflow, as `x` references `y` that references `x`:

```py
class Ref:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.value = None

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.value is None:
            return self.name
        return f"{self.name}={self.value!r}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x, y = Ref("x"), Ref("y")

    x.value = (1, y)
    y.value = (2, x)

    print(x)
    print(y)
```

But as I test it with CPython 3.10.4, it works out of the box!

```
x=(1, y=(2, x=(...)))
y=(2, x=(1, y=(...)))
```

I can't find when this behavior changed. I see [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231477/unintended-recursive-loop-with-repr-method) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858921/how-do-i-handle-recursive-reprs-in-python) as recent as 2020 wondering how to handle mutually- or self-recursive data structures. I also found about the [`reprlib` builtin library](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/reprlib.html) which produces similar output, so I suspect some language dev decided to use it by default.

Note: I also tested it with `__str__` and it also works, so it's not specific to `repr()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually never really did, and still doesn't as of today (version 3.12.0 alpha 0).

The case you show is the simplest possible one: recursive `repr` with instances of the same class. In such case, it's pretty easy for the interpreter to detect that the `repr` is going to cause infinite recursion and therefore stop and produce `...` instead: it just needs to check whether the `.__repr__()` method for the current class is asking for the `.__repr__()` of an instance of the same class.

This has been supported since Python 1.5.1 (1998!) as can be seen in [`Misc/HISTORY`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Misc/HISTORY):

```
========================================
==> Release 1.5.1 (October 31, 1998) <==
========================================

[...]

- No longer a core dump when attempting to print (or repr(), or str())
a list or dictionary that contains an instance of itself; instead, the
recursive entry is printed as [...] or {...}.  See Py_ReprEnter() and
Py_ReprLeave() below.  Comparisons of such objects still go beserk,
since this requires a different kind of fix; fortunately, this is a
less common scenario in practice.
```

Any slightly more complex case will still cause trouble even on the latest CPython version:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.value!r}"

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.value!r}"

a, b = A(), B()
a.value = b
b.value = a

print(a)
# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of an object
```